# Video steganography

Tags: matlab, video, frames, steganography

I am working on Video steganography using Matlab I have completed my encryption on video successfully but the problem is that I am not able to retrieve my data back in decryption module.

After splitting encoded video into frames i am not able to retrieve the encoded frame from the video.Please give your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unless you show us your code and identify the specific problem you're facing, you can't expect much feedback from the community. Look at the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [sscee](http://www.sscce.org/) for how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a lossy compression codec, it might be messing with your data when it compress the frames. Try using a lossless codec. Wikipedia has a list of such codecs [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs#Lossless_compression_2).

Comment: Sir I think that i am not applying any type of compression on the video frames as a result whenever i am encrypting the frame the size of the frame increases as compare to original frame. And thnxs for your the ans.